# return Statement from each branching

Tags: java, if-statement, return

Some times I found some compilation error like this -

```
public static boolean returnTrueFalse(){

   if(someConditions) return true;

   if(someConditions){
      //do something
      return true;
   }

   if(someConditions){
      //do something
      return false;
   }

   //GOT A COMPILATION ERROR HERE


}
```

In above situation we got a compilation error at the commented portion saying -  `missing return statement`. So how can we avoid this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Lets say that your conditions are `if(x>10)` `if(x>5)` and `if(x>0)`. What should happen for `x = -1`? Did you make sure that your method will return value for cases which you didn't handle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: pick one from here -> http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+missing+return+statement

Answer (score 1):

Well, the message of the compile error is pretty clear : your code must encounter a return statement of every possible execution path because your method has a non-void return type. Just add a return statement for the last case, or throw an exception if you should not reach this state in a normal execution.

Answer (score 1):

Or you may use the following structure. Use `return` statement from a single point by the help of `boolean` variable `decision` -

```
public static boolean returnTrueFalse(){

   boolean decision = false //or may be true based on your situation.

   if(someConditions) decision =  true;

   if(someConditions){
      //do something
      decision =  true;
   }

   if(someConditions){
      //do something
      decision =  false;
   }

   //returns at last; a single return
   //no branching
   return decision;


}
```

Now here is no branching due to multiple `return` statement. So no compilation error.

Comment: While it may be good idea it is worth noticing that your code will not always act same as one in OP example, where if first `someConditions` will be true it `true` will be returned and rest of code in method will not execute. It is good visible with `if (i>2) true; if (i>1) true; if(i>0) false;` so we will always end up with `false` since all of these conditions are sub-conditions of `i>0`.

Comment: @Pshemo, Thanks for the great finding. Once I also faced the same situations the OP mentioned and I recover from this situation using this idea. Then I did not think about these case, somehow I survived :) . From now I have to consider about the situation you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return` statement outside of any `if`, or add an `else` to one of those `if` statements. Your function is of type `boolean` and should return type `boolean`, without a return its of type void.

Comment: Preferably the last one, otherwise parts of the code will be dead...